# Solving MLE(Maximum Likelihood Estimation) equation using SYMPY

Tags: python, sympy, modeling, mathematical-expressions

I have an equation in 4 variables x, v, eta(e), beta(b). I want to substitute x and v with various values and create an equation by multiplying all the obtained terms. 
[Image of Code in sympy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2fXG.png)

Using SYMPY, How to solve the obtained equation in 2 variables(e and b) taking a log and differentiating with respect to e and then b?
I am taking 'ln' so that the multiplicative terms get simplified to additive terms and hence exponential terms get eliminated. But, it is not happening. It just writes the word log in front but doesn't expand using the property ln(mn) = ln(m) + ln(n)

Following is the output in console:

[Output in console when I run code shown in previous image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmRuD.png)

Comment: Please provide your code in a format that can be copy-pasted. In the meantime, try calling `sp.expand_log` with the option `force=True`

Comment: @Stelios, I am still not able to eliminate the exponential terms from after force = true in expand_log
PFB code:

from sympy.solvers.pde import pdsolve
from sympy import Function , diff , Eq
from sympy.abc import x,y,z,v
from sympy import *
# from sympy import IndexedBase , Idx, symbols , oo
import sympy as sp
# import numpy
# from mpmath import *
# from sympy.tensor.array import Array
e, b, a= sp.symbols('e b a')

Continued.....

Comment: x = sp.IndexedBase('x')
v = sp.IndexedBase('v')
i , j = sp.symbols('i j' , cls=Idx)
 

def f(x, v, e, b):
      
    y = (((x + v)/e)**(b-1))*(sp.exp((v/e)**b - ((x+v)/e)**b))
    return y
# 
# 
n= 0
for i in range(0,6):   
    
    x = x[i].subs(x[i], (2,3,4,5,4,1))
    
    v = v[i].subs(v[i],(1,2,3,4,5,6))
    
    o = sp.ln(f(x[i],v[i],e,b))
    
    n += o    
print(n)
def m(e,b):
      
    m= sp.expand_log(sp.ln(n))
     
    return m 
print(m(e,b))
eqs = (sp.diff(n,e) , sp.diff(n,b))
 
print(eqs)
print(sp.solve(eqs))

Comment: I made some changes in code:

Please see below

n= 1
for i in range(0,6):   
    
    x = x[i].subs(x[i], (2,3,4,5,4,1))
    
    v = v[i].subs(v[i],(1,2,3,4,5,6))
    
    n *= f(x[i],v[i],e,b) 
    
print(n)
def m(e,b):
      
    m= sp.expand_log(sp.ln(n), force= true)
    sp.simplify(m) 
    return m 
print(m(e,b))

eqs = (sp.diff(m(e,b),e) , sp.diff(m(e,b),b))
  
print(eqs)
print(sp.solve(eqs))

Now the exponential terms are eliminated, thanks @Stelios
But error 'could not solve equations' in console remains the same.

Comment: Please paste your code here. No one is going to attempt to retype your code from an image.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set your various symbols as positive, like `x = symbols('x', positive=True)`. Identities like `log(x*y) == log(x) + log(y)` and `log(exp(x)) == x` are not true in general, but they are true when the variables are positive.